# Holonomic mobile base using gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, mobile

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new in this field..I need to do the coding holonomic mobile base using gazebo..

The robot must able to move in any direction (not only on curve trayectories like a car).

To achieve this we use 4 wheels and each wheel has 2 degrees of freedom: it can rotate but it can also steer independently from all the others).

In total there are therefore 8 motors.

```
The base platform containing of four wheels, each wheel has 2 degrees of freedom. It is a holonomic wheel base. There are two motors connected to each wheel, one is used for steering and the other is used for driving. The wheel is no deformable planar circle type. Therefore, each wheel has the capability of steering and driving independently.
```

We also suggest to add a lateral offset between the wheel and the vertical axis of rotation. In this way we can reduce the friction during steering, because we add a rolling movement which support steering (software must take this new kinematic into account).

so help me to do dis?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30629/holonomic-mobile-base-using-gazebo../) by [SHAKIMCA](https://answers.ros.org/users/2068/shakimca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-03-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-04-07**:
do you need reference for both simulation and controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From what I understand, this is the same configuration used by the [PR2](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_description) and the [Care-O-Bot](http://www.ros.org/wiki/care-o-bot). You can therefore have a look at these packages for inspiration/reference.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-04-07**:
p.s. just want to mention that PR2 is not truly holonomic.